# Laravel fetch post request returns required errors when my inputs are not empty

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am making an ajax post request to my post controller. But i am getting `required` errors for all my inputs in `json`, even if i fill the inputs. I am trying to fix this issue, but i am unable to fix it. I am stuck.
**My JS Code:**
// Ad form

```
class AdForm {
    constructor() {
        this.form = $('form.adForm');
        this.submitButton = $('button.adForm-submitBtn');
        this.errorsElem = $('.adForm-errors');
        this.successElem = $('.adForm-success');

        this.submitAd();
    }

    submitAd() {
        this.submitButton.on('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const self = $(e.currentTarget);
            const form = self.parents('form');
            const actionUrl = form.attr('action');
            const token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

            this.errorsElem.hide();

            this.submitAdRequest(actionUrl, form, token);
        });
    }

    async submitAdRequest(actionUrl, form, token) {
        console.log(form[0]);
        console.log(actionUrl);
        try {
            const response = await fetch(actionUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    "X-CSRF-Token": token
                },
                method: "POST",
                body: new FormData(form[0])
            });
            const body = await response.json();
            console.log(body.errors);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
const adForm = new AdForm();
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'condition' => 'required',
        'county' => 'required',
        'municipality' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'images' => 'required',
        'images.*' => 'max:2500',
        'category' => 'required'
    ]);

    $title = $request->input('title');
    $description = $request->input('description');
    $condition = $request->input('condition');
    $country = $request->input('country');
    $county = $request->input('county');
    $municipality = $request->input('municipality');
    $address = $request->input('address');
    $price = $request->input('price');
    $category = $request->input('category');

    $allowedfileExtension = ['jpeg','jpg','png'];

    $files = [];
    if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
        $images = $request->file('images');
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);
            if (!$check) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Images must be png, jpeg or jpg!');
            }
            $name = Str::random(30) . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);  
            $files[] = $name;
        }
    }
    $files = json_encode($files);

    Ads::insert([
        ['user' => Auth::user()->id, 'title' => $title, 'description' => $description,
        'condition' => $condition, 'county' => $county, 'municipality' => $municipality, 
        'address' => $address, 'price' => $price, 'images' => $files, 'category' => $category, 
        'created_at' => now(), 'updated_at' => now()]
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your ad has been created!');
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Can someone please tell me, what is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE**
I got a solution and it is working now. I am first getting all form fields values and putting them in object and passing them in `fetch request's body`  like `JSON.stringify(formData)`, but it's not working for images.

```
submitAd() {
    this.form.on('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const self = $(e.currentTarget);
        const form = self;
        const actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        const token = form.find('input[name="_token"]').val();

        // Get values
        const title = form.find('input[name=title]').val();
        const description = form.find('textarea[name=description]').val();
        const condition = form.find('input[name=condition]').val();
        const category = form.find('select[name=category]').val();
        const price = form.find('input[name=price]').val();
        const county = form.find('select[name=county]').val();
        const municipality = form.find('select[name=municipality]').val();
        const address = form.find('input[name=address]').val();
        const images = form.find('input[name="images[]"]').val();

        const formData = {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            condition: condition,
            category: category,
            price: price,
            county: county,
            municipality: municipality,
            address: address,
            images: images
        };

        this.errorsElem.hide();

        this.submitAdRequest(actionUrl, formData, token);
    });
}

async submitAdRequest(actionUrl, formData, token) {
    console.log(formData);
    try {
        const response = await fetch(actionUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRF-Token": token
            },
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        });
        const body = await response.json();
        console.log(body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me, how can I make it work for images too?

Comment: make the request with your network tab open in the debugger and see if anything is sent. you might need to serialize the form to send it.

Comment: I have added the network tab screenshot, please check

Comment: Try to use `serialize()`: `body: form[0].serialize()`

Comment: @HuyPhạm no, it gives me `form[0].serialize is not a function` error. It should be only `form.serialize()`, but it is also the same. i mean it is also gives me `required` errors for all filled inputs

Comment: what about form.serialize or new FormData(form);    if that doesn't work then set each element of the form separately.  const form = new FormData(); form.set('city', 'oslo'); form.set('county', 'Oslo');

Comment: hmm don't think you can send image data via text/json

Comment: You are specifying ContentType application/json but do not send a JSON body, but rather FormData. The formats needs to match, otherwise Laravel cannot decode it

Comment: @TobiasK. FormData is a json, no? how can i fix it? Can you improve me code?

Comment: FormData is something like `a=val1&b=valB` (multipart is different again, cannot show that in a comment) while JSON is `{"a":"valA","b":"valB"}`. Either CAN be used but it needs to match the Content-Type header of the Request.

Comment: So what will be the `Content-Type` if i use `FormData`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the working code, but it's not working for images. Please check the updated section of my question.

Comment: Imo you're better off using a "normal" multipart payload. Sending images by JSON requires base64 encoding their content which is a big overhead

Comment: What should i do? Is there not any way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good in JS but I believe it is the JS `AdForm` class that causing the issue. You are defining the submit action during constructor and using the async ajax for fetching the result.

So when the `AdForm` object is initiated and used in the script, it already had captures the form data in its empty state and thus sending the empty form data.

Comment: I am calling the `submit` function in the constructor, i am not trigger the submit button in the conatructor, when it submits the form, it captures the updated values.